# Function in reading memory ptr

Tags: function, pointers

I made a program that reads values of resources of each player in a game, it indicates to me when something is being built based on what is used from the resoUrces, how do i make a function / if statement which would be if resources subtract 100 is equal to new resource then do this… thanks

Comment: By writing the code that does exactly that? It's unclear what the problem is, especially since you have shown no code and not tagged any programming language

Comment: I havent been able to do that part, as of now i only view resources, and have a few statements if (R=200) its in c++ ..